# How to sort a complex object by a nested value

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble trying to sort a complex object. This is the object structure:

```
[{
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542088800000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 480
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}, {
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542096000000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 373
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}, {
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542103200000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 683
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}]
```

Basically it is an array of objects that have a property called "searchResultProperties", which is an array of objects with "key" and "value" properties.

I'm trying to sort on the "key" property, ie: "size_byte AVG".

Comment: Can you please also post your attempt?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to sort the objects in the array, by one of their properties, or you want to sort the object's properties, which seems an odd thing to do?

Comment: I want to sort the objects in array based on one of tue properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

sort takes two values as argument. With find we find the array element with key `'size_byte AVG'` and take out value from it and compare values

```js
let arr = [{"searchResultProperties": [{"key": "message_time","value": 1542088800000}, {"key": "size_byte AVG","value": 480}, {"key": "source_file",       "value": "log"}, {"key": "source_host","value": "lab8.domain.com"}],"show": false,"key": null, "type": null}, { "searchResultProperties": [{"key": "message_time","value": 1542096000000}, {"key": "size_byte AVG","value": 373}, {"key": "source_file","value": "log"}, {"key": "source_host","value": "lab8.domain.com"}],"show": false,"key": null, "type": null}, {"searchResultProperties": [{"key": "message_time","value": 1542103200000}, {"key": "size_byte AVG","value": 683 }, { "key": "source_file","value": "log"}, {"key": "source_host","value": "lab8.domain.com"}],"show": false,"key": null,"type": null}]

let op = arr.sort((a,b)=>
         a.searchResultProperties.find(e=>e.key==='size_byte AVG').value -
         b.searchResultProperties.find(e=>e.key==='size_byte AVG').value)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thanks! But this one not works for the "source_file" field because it isn't a int.

Comment: @Pennywise83 this can be easily modified now according to requirement isn't it ? Btw you can use `Intl.collator` if you want it to work for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.prototype.sort()` function that gives you two objects and you can return a +ve or -ve value based on your logic to sort. Refer [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort ]

```js
array = [{
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542088800000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 480
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}, {
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542096000000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 373
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}, {
    "searchResultProperties": [{
        "key": "message_time",
        "value": 1542103200000
    }, {
        "key": "size_byte AVG",
        "value": 683
    }, {
        "key": "source_file",
        "value": "log"
    }, {
        "key": "source_host",
        "value": "lab8.domain.com"
    }],
    "show": false,
    "key": null,
    "type": null
}]

array = array.sort((a,b) => a.searchResultProperties.find(obj => obj.key === "size_byte AVG").value - b.searchResultProperties.find(obj => obj.key === "size_byte AVG").value )

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I was writing an answer and wanted to give  a quick reply in the mean time so that the author can attempt himself

Comment: still not explaining why your code helps the OP and what OP was doing wrong

Comment: @CalvinNunes the OP has not shared his code. So I can never say what he was doing wrong!

Comment: The code helps because it works and sorts! Its a one line solution! Why would you expect me to complicate and write an essay when the code does its own talking !

Comment: Ok, now you have a text that explain what your code do, and help OP to understand the use of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `find` to look for the objects with key `size_byte AVG` and the function `sort` for sorting the array.

*This approach sorts in ascending direction*

```js
let arr = [{    "searchResultProperties": [{        "key": "message_time",        "value": 1542088800000    }, {        "key": "size_byte AVG",        "value": 480    }, {        "key": "source_file",        "value": "log"    }, {        "key": "source_host",        "value": "lab8.domain.com"    }],    "show": false,    "key": null,    "type": null}, {    "searchResultProperties": [{        "key": "message_time",        "value": 1542096000000    }, {        "key": "size_byte AVG",        "value": 373    }, {        "key": "source_file",        "value": "log"    }, {        "key": "source_host",        "value": "lab8.domain.com"    }],    "show": false,    "key": null,    "type": null}, {    "searchResultProperties": [{        "key": "message_time",        "value": 1542103200000    }, {        "key": "size_byte AVG",        "value": 683    }, {        "key": "source_file",        "value": "log"    }, {        "key": "source_host",        "value": "lab8.domain.com"    }],    "show": false,    "key": null,    "type": null}],
    target = "size_byte AVG",
    compare = (a, b) => a.find(({key}) => key === target).value - b.find(({key}) => key === target).value,
    sorted = arr.sort(({searchResultProperties: a}, {searchResultProperties: b}) => compare(a, b));

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```